# Synchronizing Windows Mobile 6.5 and multiple PCs

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange-2010, windows-phone

I'm supposed to work outside home for a long period of time.

I have a home desktop PC with Outlook 2010 synchronized with my PDA. I also have a laptop: both computers run Windows 7.

I have the problem of synchronizing contacts and appointments at least on desktop and PDA (laptop is an option). If I establish a synchronization relationship between PDA and laptop, I lose all data and I have to re establish a relationship between desktop and PDA.

I also have two other useful things: a genuine license of Exchange Server 2010, courtesy of Microsoft, and a server running Linux with public IP.

I know that it could be possible to sync PDA via wifi using Exchange Server, but it looks like I can't run it in Windows 7. Also, my home computer doesn't have a public IP due to my ISP. But I still have the public server (running Linux).

## My question is

What do you suggest me to perform remote synchronization of PDA and laptop (Outlook) to a unique source at home? Is there a way either to run Exchange in Linux or an equivalent server? (I don't think so)